# What is the use of deviceadminreceiver? What is the difference with BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

What is the use of **deviceadminreceiver**, with example? Also, what is the different between it with **BroadcastReceiver**?

Answer (score 1):

A DeviceAdminReceiver is a subclass of BroadcastReciever that receives broadcasts relating to device policies.  You would only use this if you were writing security or enterprise provisioning software or trying to lock down a device in kiosk mode.  Its kind of an esoteric part of Android.

Comment: thanks @Gabe  Sechan sir  as I am new android programming